repeated topic, use namespace vs one topic only, scalability
The setup is as following:
It has several Raspberry Pi and to each several Arduino are attached that have each one sensor.
         ---- Arduino1 - sensor1
         |
RPi 1  --|--- Arduino2 - sensor2
         |
         ---- Arduino3 - sensor3
         
         
         ---- Arduino4 - sensor4
RPi 2  --|
         ---- Arduino5 - sensor5
         
...


The number of RPi and Arduino should be as variable as possible (scalability).
The code on each Arduino is exactly the same. It advertises to a topic "value" reading the value regularly and subscribes to a topic "command" to configure the sensor. This is easier to deploy the application.
The machine id of all Arduino is known (using /dev/serial/by-id symbolic link).

What is the best way to implement this?
In the launch file, I prefer to just add one line for one sensor being added.
The roscore is launched somewhere and connects to the RPis via network.
<launch>
    <machine name="rpi1" address="pc_rpi1"></machine>
    <machine name="rpi2" address="pc_rpi2"></machine>
    <machine name="rpi3" address="pc_rpi3"></machine>
    
    <node machine="rpi1" name="s1" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py">
        <param name="port" value="/dev/serial/by-id/....1"/>
        <param name="baud" value="9600" />
    </node>
    <node machine="rpi1" name="s2" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py">
        <param name="port" value="/dev/serial/by-id/....2"/>
        <param name="baud" value="9600" />
    </node>
    <node machine="rpi1" name="s3" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py">
        <param name="port" value="/dev/serial/by-id/....3"/>
        <param name="baud" value="9600" />
    </node>
    <node machine="rpi2" name="s4" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py">
        <param name="port" value="/dev/serial/by-id/....4"/>
        <param name="baud" value="9600" />
    </node>
    <node machine="rpi2" name="s5" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py">
        <param name="port" value="/dev/serial/by-id/....5"/>
        <param name="baud" value="9600" />
    </node>
</launch>

Can I get the name of the machine that reports the sensor, or how can I distinguish between the values reported from the same topic properly? Is there a better alternative?
